# Is there a shorter way to pull groups out of a Powershell regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

In PowerShell I find myself doing this kind of thing over and over again for matches:

```
some-command | select-string '^(//[^#]*)' |
     %{some-other-command $_.matches[0].groups[1].value}
```

So basically - run a command that generates lines of text, and for each line I want to run a command on a regex capture inside the line (if it matches). Seems really simple. The above works, but is there a shorter way to pull out those regex capture groups? Perl had $1 and so on, if I remember right. Posh has to have something similar, right? I've seen "$matches" references on SO but can't figure out what makes that get set.

I'm very new to PowerShell btw, just started learning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `-match` operator to reformulate your command as:

```
some-command | Foreach-Object { if($_ -match '^(//[^#]*)') { some-other-command $($matches[1])}}
```

Comment: Eh? He's matching a line that starts with double-slash (//) and greedily matching up until (but excluding) the first hash (#). There is no end-of-line marker, so he's not specifically matching the entire line.

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks for the edit, Bas.

Answer (score 8):

Named Replacement

```
'foo bar' -replace '(?<First>foo).+', '${First}'
```

Returns: foo

Unnamed Replacement

```
 'foo bar' -replace '(foo).+(ar)', '$2 z$2 $1'
```

Returns: ar zar foo

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
Get-Content foo.txt | foreach { some-othercommand [regex]::match($_,'^(//[^#]*)').value }
```

Comment: For me this outputs a blank line if the input doesn't match. [Bas Bossink](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1011163/111424)'s answer works like this one but outputs only the matches.