# Retrieve text in HTML with powershell

Tags: html, regex, powershell

In this html code :

```
<div id="ajaxWarningRegion" class="infoFont"></div>
  <span id="ajaxStatusRegion"></span>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="confIPBackupForm" action="/cgi-bin/utilserv/confIPBackup/w_confIPBackup" id="confIPBackupForm" >
    <pre>
      Creating a new ZIP of IP Phone files from HTTP/PhoneBackup 
      and HTTPS/PhoneBackup
    </pre>
    <pre> /tmp/IP_PHONE_BACKUP-2012-Jul-25_15:47:47.zip</pre>
    <pre>Reports Success</pre>
    <pre></pre>
    <a href =  /tmp/IP_PHONE_BACKUP-2012-Jul-25_15:47:47.zip>
      Download the new ZIP of IP Phone files
    </a>
  </div>
```

I want to retrieve the text `IP_PHONE_BACKUP-2012-Jul-25_15:47:47.zip` or just the date and hour between `IP_PHONE_BACKUP-` and `.zip`

How can I do that ?

Comment: [Regular expressions are the wrong approach to parsing HTML (or XML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Richard, I'd disagree in this case. What they want to extract actually has nothing to do with HTML, XML or any other non-regular language. It's just a string from which they want to extract a date.

Answer (score 10):

What makes this question so interesting is that HTML looks and smells just like XML, the latter being much more programmably palatable due to its well-behaved and orderly structure. In an ideal world HTML would be a subset of XML, but HTML in the real-world is emphatically *not* XML. If you feed the example in the question into any XML parser it will balk on a variety of infractions. That being said, the desired result can be achieved with a single line of PowerShell. This one returns the whole text of the href:

```
Select-NodeContent $doc.DocumentNode "//a/@href"
```

And this one extracts the desired substring:

```
Select-NodeContent $doc.DocumentNode "//a/@href" "IP_PHONE_BACKUP-(.*)\.zip"
```

The catch, however, is in the overhead/setup to be able to run that one line of code. You need to:

- **Install [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)** to make HTML parsing look just like XML parsing.
- **Install [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)** if you want to parse a live web page.
- **Understand XPath** to be able to construct a navigable path to your target node.
- **Understand regular expressions** to be able to extract a substring from your target node.

With those requirements satisfied you can add the `HTMLAgilityPath` type to your environment and define the `Select-NodeContent` function, both shown below. The very end of the code shows how you assign a value to the `$doc` variable used in the above one-liners. I show how to load HTML from a file or from the web, depending on your needs.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$HtmlAgilityPackPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine((Get-Item $PROFILE).DirectoryName, "bin\HtmlAgilityPack.dll")
Add-Type -Path $HtmlAgilityPackPath

function Select-NodeContent(
    [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]$node,
    [string] $xpath,
    [string] $regex,
    [Object] $default = "")
{
    if ($xpath -match "(.*)/@(\w+)$") {
        # If standard XPath to retrieve an attribute is given,
        # map to supported operations to retrieve the attribute's text.
        ($xpath, $attribute) = $matches[1], $matches[2]
        $resultNode = $node.SelectSingleNode($xpath)
        $text = ?: { $resultNode } { $resultNode.Attributes[$attribute].Value } { $default }
    }
    else { # retrieve an element's text
        $resultNode = $node.SelectSingleNode($xpath)
        $text = ?: { $resultNode } { $resultNode.InnerText } { $default }
    }
    # If a regex is given, use it to extract a substring from the text
    if ($regex) {
        if ($text -match $regex) { $text = $matches[1] }
        else { $text = $default }
    }
    return $text
}

$doc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$result = $doc.Load("tmp\temp.html") # Use this to load a file
#$result = $doc.LoadHtml((Get-HttpResource $url)) # Use this  PSCX cmdlet to load a live web page
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the HTML surrounding your file name is irrelevant here. You can extract the date just fine with the following regex (which doesn't even care whether you're extracting it from an e-mail an HTML page or a CSV file):

```
(?<=/tmp/IP_PHONE_BACKUP-)[^.]+(?=\.zip)
```

Quick test:

```
PS> [regex]::Match($html, '(?<=/tmp/IP_PHONE_BACKUP-)[^.]+(?=\.zip)')

Groups   : {2012-Jul-25_15:47:47}
Success  : True
Captures : {2012-Jul-25_15:47:47}
Index    : 391
Length   : 20
Value    : 2012-Jul-25_15:47:47
```

Answer (score 0):

The group(2) and group(3) of the following regex receptively contains the date and time:

```
/IP_PHONE_BACKUP-((.*)_(.*)).zip/
```

Here is a link to extract the value from a regex in powershell.

[Is there a shorter way to pull groups out of a Powershell regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010924/is-there-a-shorter-way-to-pull-groups-out-of-a-powershell-regex)

HIH

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
$a = '<div id="ajaxWarningRegion" class="infoFont"></div><span id="ajaxStatusRegion"></span><form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="confIPBackupForm" action="/cgi-bin/utilserv/confIPBackup/w_confIPBackup" id="confIPBackupForm" ><pre>Creating a new ZIP of IP Phone files from HTTP/PhoneBackup and HTTPS/PhoneBackup</pre><pre> /tmp/IP_PHONE_BACKUP-2012-Jul-25_15:47:47.zip</pre><pre>Reports Success</pre><pre></pre><a href =  /tmp/IP_PHONE_BACKUP-2012-Jul-25_15:47:47.zip>Download the new ZIP of IP Phone files</a></div>'
$a.Substring($a.IndexOf("IP_PHONE_BACKUP")+"IP_PHONE_BACKUP".length+1, $a.IndexOf(".zip")-$a.IndexOf("IP_PHONE_BACKUP")-"IP_PHONE_BACKUP".length-1)
```

`Substring` gets you a part of the original string. The first parameter is the start position of the substring while the second part is the length of the desiered substring. So now all you have to do is to calculate the start and the length using a little `IndexOf`- and `Length`-magic.

Comment: Now , I have to understand how it work, because I dit not know this properties "substring" ;o)

Comment: @Littlefish I updated my answer with a little bit of explanation.

Comment: @Joey : sorry for the mistake