# Grab contents of div with regex in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a directory of similar structured HTML files (two examples given):

File-1.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">foo</div>
        <div class="bar"><div><p>bar</p></div></div>
        <div class="baz">baz</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

File-2.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">foo</div>
        <div class="bar"><div><p>apple<br>banana</p></div></div>
        <div class="baz">baz</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a Powershell script to return the contents of the `bar` div, stripped from all html:

For File-1.html: `bar`

For File-2.html: `apple banana`

I now have:

```
$directory = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sandbox\HTML"

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem($directory))
{
    $content = Get-Content $file.fullname

    $test = [regex]::matches($content, '(?i)<div class="bar">(.*)</div>')

    echo $test[0]
}
```

This returns however `<div class="bar"><div><p>bar</p></div></div><div class="baz">baz</div>`. In other words, the regex does not stop until the last `</div>`. How can I let it *only* grab what in the `<div class="bar">` div?

Comment: read here for some suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11656434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, quantifers are [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap). They will try to match as much as possible still allowing the remainder of the regular expression to match. Use `*?` for a non-greedy match meaning "zero or more — preferably as few as possible".

```
(?si)<div class="bar">(.*?)</div>
```