# Regex match Improvement

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this text:

```
<td class="devices-user-name">devicename</td>
            <td>192.168.133.221</td>
            <td>Storage Sync</td>
            <td>10.3.3.335</td>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>7/26/2016 8:39PM</td>
            <td class="devices-details-button"><a class="btn btn-mini" href="#settings/devices/1/239a9cd0-d6c9-4e7d-9918-0cd686a57aac">Details</a></td>
```

I want to catch everything between the `<td> </td>` as well the `<td class=...> </td>`

What I achieved is this regex:

```
<td.*>(.*?)<\/td>(\n(.*<td>(.*?)<\/td>))(\n(.*<td>(.*?)<\/td>))(\n(.*<td>(.*?)<\/td>))(\n(.*<td>(.*?)<\/td>))(\n(.*<td>(.*?)<\/td>))(\n(.*<td.*href="(.*?)"))
```

After that I still need to exclude all the `<td>` matches:

```
$MatchResult = $Matches.GetEnumerator() | ? {$_.Value -notmatch 'td'} | Sort Name
```

Finally I get this results:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              devicename
4                              192.168.133.221
7                              Storage Sync
10                             10.3.3.335
13                             Active
16                             7/26/2016 8:39PM
19                             #settings/devices/1/239a9cd0-d6c9-4e7d-9918-0cd686a57aac
```

But I'm quiet sure that there's a better way, instead of duplicating the groups, excluding stuff etc. to use some other/better technics, which I'll be happy to learn.

What is your suggestion?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11656434/3832970 for an alternative method.

Comment: Concerning parsing HTML with RegEx, [please read this first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[regex]::Matches` to get multiple matches (instead of using `\n`):

```
$content = Get-Content 'your-File'
[regex]::Matches($content , '<td.*?>(.+?)<\/td>') | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
}
```

**Regex:**

```
<td.*?>(.+?)<\/td>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Output:**

```
devicename
192.168.133.221
Storage Sync
10.3.3.335
Active
7/26/2016 8:39PM
<a class="btn btn-mini" href="#settings/devices/1/239a9cd0-d6c9-4e7d-9918-0cd686a57aac">Details</a>
```

---

**Note:** You probably want to extract the href in another step or by adjusting the regex - but you question was about catching everything between `<td>`...

Comment: `<td[^>]*>(.+)<\/td>` For the example provided, this works in about 1/3rd the number of steps, as lazy evaluations are notoriously slow. It will work as long as each `<td>` is on it's own line, as `.` won't normally consume newlines. Just depends on the source being parsed.

Comment: Well mentioned. If he want to stick with regex to parse his html? he probably have to add `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]`...

Comment: Can i use something like `'<td.*?>(.+?)<\/td>'{3}` for 3 times for example?